# Phaser 3 (Game framework): collider callback is called, but somethimes object still passes through other object, instead of colliding

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm working on a small *flappy-bird-like-game* demo. Everthing seems fine, but I have a small problem/question.

I setup a `collider` function, and the callback works as expected, when the "two" objects collide, but there is a strange behavior:

- the white-square *(the bird)* can fly through the obstacles, when coming from the side
- but cannot passthrough when coming from below or on above

**BUT** the callback is execute always.

***blue arrow** marks where the square passes through*
***green arrows** mark where the square doesn't passthrough*

[image: screenshot of game error]

I'm not sure if this is, because I'm using rectangles *(they sometimes)* cause problems, or because of my nested physics setup. *I even tried to replaced the white rectangel with a sprite, but this still produces the same result/error.*

> **For my demo:** I could probablly just destroy the object and restart the level on collision, but I still would like to understand why this is happening? And how I can prevent this, inconsistant behavior.
> *I'm probably missing something, but couldn't find it, and I don't want to rebuild the application again.*

**So my question is:** why is this happening? And How can I prevent this?

**Here is the code:**

```js
const width = 400;
const height = 200;

const spacing = width / 4;

const levelSpeed = width / 4;
const flySpeed = width / 4;

var GameScene = {
    create (){

    let player = this.add.rectangle(width / 4, height / 2, 20, 20, 0xffffff);
    this.physics.add.existing(player);

    this.input.keyboard.on('keydown-SPACE', (event) => {
        if(player.body.velocity.y >= -flySpeed/2){
            player.body.setVelocityY(-flySpeed);
        }
    });

    player.body.onWorldBounds = true;
    player.body.setCollideWorldBounds(true );

    this.physics.world.on("worldbounds", function (body) {
      console.info('GAME OVER');
      player.y = height / 2;
      player.body.setVelocity(0);
    });

    this.pipes = [];

    for(let idx = 1; idx <= 10; idx++) {
        let obstacle = this.createObstacle(spacing * idx, Phaser.Math.Between(-height/3, 0));
        this.add.existing(obstacle);
        this.pipes.push(obstacle);
        
        this.physics.add.collider(obstacle.list[0], player)
        this.physics.add.collider(obstacle.list[1], player, _ => console.info(2))
    }
},

update(){
    this.pipes.forEach((item) => {
        if(item.x <= 0){
            item.body.x = spacing * 10;
        } 
    })
},
extend: {
    createObstacle (x, y){

        let topPipe = (new Phaser.GameObjects.Rectangle(this, 0, 0 , 20 , height / 2 ,0xff0000)).setOrigin(0);
        let bottomPipe = (new Phaser.GameObjects.Rectangle(this, 0, height/2 + 75, 20 , height / 2 ,0xff0000)).setOrigin(0);

        this.physics.add.existing(topPipe);
        this.physics.add.existing(bottomPipe);
        
        topPipe.body.setImmovable(true);
        topPipe.body.allowGravity = false;

        bottomPipe.body.setImmovable(true);
        bottomPipe.body.allowGravity = false;

        let obstacle = new Phaser.GameObjects.Container(this, x, y, [
            topPipe,
            bottomPipe
        ]);

        this.physics.add.existing(obstacle);

        obstacle.body.velocity.x = - levelSpeed;
        obstacle.body.allowGravity = false;

        return obstacle;
    }
}
};



var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    parent: 'phaser-example',
    width,
    height,
    scene: [GameScene],
    physics: {
        default: 'arcade',
        arcade: {
            gravity: { y: flySpeed },
            debug: true
        },
    }
};

var game = new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently I just can assume, that the physics objects don't seem to work correct, when physics objects are nested.

**Maybe I'm wrong,** but since I rewrote the code again without *nested* physics - objects and it seems to work, I think my assumption Is correct. *I shouldn't have tried to over engineer my code.*

> *If someone has more insides, please let me know/share. I still not 100% sure, if this is the real reason, for the strange behavior.*

**Here the rewriten code:**

```js
const width = 400;
const height = 200;

const spacing = width / 4;

const levelSpeed = width / 4;
const flySpeed = width / 4;

var GameScene = {
    create (){

    let player = this.add.rectangle(width / 4, height / 2, 20, 20, 0xffffff);
    this.physics.add.existing(player);

    this.input.keyboard.on('keydown-SPACE', (event) => {
        if(player.body.velocity.y >= -flySpeed/2){
            player.body.setVelocityY(-flySpeed);
        }
    });

    player.body.onWorldBounds = true;
    player.body.setCollideWorldBounds(true );

    this.physics.world.on("worldbounds", function (body) {
      console.info('GAME OVER');
      player.x = width / 4;
      player.y = height / 2;
      player.body.setVelocity(0);
    });

    this.pipes = [];

    for(let idx = 1; idx <= 10; idx++) {
        let obstacle = this.createObstacle(spacing * idx, Phaser.Math.Between(-height/3, 0));
        this.add.existing(obstacle[0]);
        this.add.existing(obstacle[1]);
        this.pipes.push(...obstacle);
        
        this.physics.add.collider(obstacle[0], player)
        this.physics.add.collider(obstacle[1], player, _ => console.info(2))
    }
},

update(){
    this.pipes.forEach((item) => {
        if(item.x <= 0){
            item.body.x = spacing * 10;
        } 
        item.body.velocity.x = - levelSpeed;
    })
},
extend: {
    createObstacle (x, y){

        let topPipe = (new Phaser.GameObjects.Rectangle(this, x, -20 , 20 , height / 2 ,0xff0000)).setOrigin(0);
        let bottomPipe = (new Phaser.GameObjects.Rectangle(this, x, height/2 + 75, 20 , height / 2 ,0xff0000)).setOrigin(0);

        this.physics.add.existing(topPipe);
        this.physics.add.existing(bottomPipe);
        
        topPipe.body.setImmovable(true);
        topPipe.body.allowGravity = false;
        topPipe.body.velocity.x = - levelSpeed;

        bottomPipe.body.setImmovable(true);
        bottomPipe.body.allowGravity = false;
        bottomPipe.body.velocity.x = - levelSpeed;

        return [topPipe, bottomPipe];
    }
}
};



var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    parent: 'phaser-example',
    width,
    height,
    scene: [GameScene],
    physics: {
        default: 'arcade',
        arcade: {
            gravity: { y: flySpeed },
            debug: true
        },
    }
};

var game = new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```